# Use of Variables for Multiple Independent PL SQL Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, substitution

I have a PL/SQL script `Test.sql` which consists of three independent queries within it.

Test.sql

```
SELECT ABC.* 
  FROM Student ABC, Teacher BCD
 WHERE 1=1
   AND ABC.Period = &Period 
   AND ABC.StudentID = BCD.StudentID;


SELECT ABC.CandidateID 
  from Student ABC
 where not exists(
                  select 1
                    from Teacher BCD
                   where ABC.StudentID = BCD.StudentID
                     AND ABC.Period = &&Period
                 ); 


SELECT BCD.CandidateID 
  from Teacher BCD
 where not exists (
                   select 1
                     from Student ABC
                    where ABC.StudentID = BCD.StudentID
                  )
   AND ABC.Period = &&Period;
```

---

Question here is, can I use one User prompt and use the user input for all the three queries? I did try using && for the subsequent variables, but that keeps the user input active for the entire session. I may need to run this script multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `&&varname` for the fist time, a substitution variable gets defined and gets undefined only when you restart SQL*PLUS, not the session. So, if you want for SQL*PLUS to prompt you for a new value every time you run you script, you can either [undefine](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#sthref969) the variable and run the script preceding variable name with double ampersand, or use [accept](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#BACGJIHF) command. Here is an example:

1. Using `undefine` command:

   ```
   undefine period

   -- precede variable name with double ampersand(variable gets defined)  
   -- the first time you reference it in a query.
   -- In subsequent references the variable can be preceded with 
   -- single ampersand.
   ...
   and ABC.Period = &&Period  

   ...
   and ABC.Period = &Period
   ```
2. Using `accept` command, which will define `<<variable_name>>` substitution variable:

   ```
   accept period number prompt 'Input period: '

   -- now you can reference `period` substitution variable
   -- in your script prefixing its name with ampersand sign

   ...
   and ABC.Period = &period
   ```

Comment: Zillion Thanks Nicholas. That was quick! :)